# IE6 and IE7 float issue on navigation list items

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float, internet-explorer-6

Like many people, I am having trouble with floating elements in IE7 (and 6, but I don't care about that!)

http://www.storybox.co.nz/wordpress/

Looks fine in every other browser, but in IE7 the navigation links sit under each other: 
[image]

HTML (inline styles are from js dropdown script):

```
<div id="primary-menu">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Work.</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="float: none; width: 1em; visibility: hidden; display: none;">
          <li style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;"><a href="#" style="float: none; width: auto;">Spatial /</a></li>
          <li style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;"><a href="#" style="float: none; width: auto;">Web /</a></li>
          <li style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;"><a href="#" style="float: none; width: auto;">Graphic</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lab.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About.</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#primary-menu {
    margin:-30px auto 30px;
}
#primary-menu ul {
    float:right;
}
#primary-menu li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 10px;
            display:inline;
}
#primary-menu ul li a {
        float: right;
}
```

I have tried display:inline on the `li` items as well as on the `a` items, but that doesn't work.

Any other tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is probably width: 100% for li. If ul is 100px, then each of li will also have 100px = they will be displayed as shown. Try to set fixed width for them, but 3x width ( + padding, margins ) should be less than width for ul. You can also try 33%. BT

float: right puts display: block on item and it makes no sense to add display: inline together with float: right. My guess is that IE ignores display: inline. It makes also no sense to put width for inline element. Your CSS simple does not make sense :)

Comment: Thanks @mkk, but as I said in my question, that width is added by the dropdown js script. I could probably change it, but I can't get rid of it.

Comment: you can overwrite it by using !important. Nevertheless, I believe that adding width to ul would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again, but what width can I put on the nav ul so that it still works when new items are added? 100% makes it align left, min-width doesn't work. I also tried setting the width of the li elements, but that breaks it.

Comment: @Caroline have you tried adding to li element width: auto !important; ? does it break it?

Comment: No it doesn't break it, but doesn't fix it either :'(

Answer (score 0):

I tested on IE 7 and below is the updated CSS.

```
#primary-menu {
   /* margin:-30px auto 30px;*/ /*Avoid negative margins*/
}
#primary-menu ul {
  float:right;
}
#primary-menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
        display:inline;
}
#primary-menu ul li a {
   /* float: right;*/ /*This caused the issue*/
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @KutePHP but I need the float:right on the anchor to ensure the 'Work' link does not jump to the left when you rollover and display the submenu.